# Multiclass Logistic regression, dealing with garbage data

Tags: python, classification, ibeacon, logistic-regression

I am creating a simple app with ibeacons which should identify what shape you have made with the ibeacon in your hand. For example, if you do a circle motion then my algorithm ( Multiclass Logistic regression ) will predict that the motion is a "circle" based on past data. Currently, I have Circle, Square, and Triangle in the database and I only care about those three shapes. However, I want to be able to filter out "other movements" as garbage data. i.e. if I just do a line motion it should process out that moment as "none of the above." Is there a way to do this with Multiclass Logistic regression?

Comment: What have you tried? The short answer is "yes"; of course you can use multiclass logit regression for this. The long answer entails a lot of signal processing (perhaps image processing -- IDK, I'm not familiar with iBeacon).

Comment: What physical mechanism are you planning to use to detect motion of the beacon?  I do not believe that the beacon's radio transmission will be significantly altered at the receiving side based on moving it in your hand.

Comment: the beacon I am using has an accelerometer inside, this trackers acceleration at frequent intervals in xyz planes. the focus isn't really on the ibeacons though I already have the data. This is more of a mathematical/ computer science question.